# Get value from a database and set it as selected value of a dropdownlist using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I get some values from a database. With one of the values I get, I would like to have that as a selected value in the dropdownlist when another dropdownlist changes. Please see code below:

**index**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select ng-model="editProject.ClientId" name="client_id" ng-options="item as item.Company for item in clientList" class="form-control">
    </select>
    <div>-->{{editProject.ClientId}}</div> <=== This is to see if I am getting the value from js
    <span style="color: red;" ng-show="formEditProject.client_id.$touched && formEditProject.client_id.$invalid">Select a client</span>
</div>
```

**js**

```
//=== This is the client list in the dropdown list ===>
$scope.editClient = {
    "ClientId": null,
    "Company": null,
    "ContactPerson": null,
    "EmailAddress": null
}

//== Retrieves clients from the database on page load ===>
$scope.getClients = function () {
    return $http.get('/Clients/GetClients')
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.clientList = response.data;
        });
};

//== Event when a different dropdownlist is changed ===>
$scope.onProjectEditChange = function () {
    console.log($scope.selectedProjectId.Id);
    $http({
            url: '/Project/GetProjectByProjectId',
            params: {
                "id": $scope.selectedProjectId.Id
            },
            method: 'post'
        })
        .then(function (response) {
        $scope.editProject.Id = response.data.Id;
        $scope.editProject.Description = response.data.Description;
        $scope.editProject.ClientId = response.data.ClientId;
        $scope.editProject.ProjectLead = response.data.ProjectLead;
        $scope.editProject.IsApproved = response.data.IsApproved;
    });
}
```

I am able to see the clientId change in the `<div>-->{{editProject.ClientId}}</div>` but it doesn't change the selected value of the dropdownlist.

Comment: `ng-options="item as item.Company for item in clientList"`: so, the value of each option is not a client ID. It''s an object (a client from the clientList). A client object can't be === to a client ID. Assuming client  ID is a string or a number, and assuming each client has an ID, the following would work: `ng-options="item.id as item.Company for item in clientList"`.

Comment: I actually got your point because when I change the dropdownlist of the client, the 'div' shows the clients object. How do I fix it then?

Comment: I edited my comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use ng-change option and check it
<div class="form-group">
    <select ng-model="editProject.ClientId" name="client_id" ng-options="item as item.Company for item in clientList" class="form-control" ng-change='changeSelectedItem(editProject.ClientId")'>
    </select>
    <div>-->{{editProject.ClientId}}</div> <=== This is to see if I am getting the value from js
    <span style="color: red;" ng-show="formEditProject.client_id.$touched && formEditProject.client_id.$invalid">Select a client</span>
</div>


$scope.changeSelectedItem = function(client){
        $scope.editProject.ClientId= client.ClientId;
}
```